# Convert json data to geoJson from URL endpoint

Tags: javascript, json, url, leaflet, geojson

I am trying to display my URL endpoint JSON data from adsbxchange URL to leaflet map or Google Maps.

I can show the map but not realtime data-points. To convert from JSON to geojson doesn't work for me, it seems to be too difficult.

I own Google Map API and Mapbox API. I tried it with leaflet at the moment. I only need a little tip for the right way to convert it.

```js
const settings = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": "https://adsbexchange-com1.p.rapidapi.com/v2/lat/47.22/lon/10.85/dist/250/",
  "method": "GET",
  "headers": {
    "X-RapidAPI-Key": "",
    "X-RapidAPI-Host": "adsbexchange-com1.p.rapidapi.com"
  }
};

$.getJSON(settings, function(response) {
  var item = response.data.ac
  for (let i = 0; i < response.data.ac.length; i = i + 1) {
    item.push([lat[i + 1], lat[i], lon[i + 1], lon[i]]);
  }

  var Geojson = {
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
      "type": "LineString",
      "coordinates": item
    }
  }

  var geojsonMarkerOptions = {
    radius: 8,
    fillColor: "#ff7800",
    color: "#000",
    weight: 1,
    opacity: 1,
    fillOpacity: 0.8
  };

  L.geoJson(Geojson, {
    style: geojsonMarkerOptions
  }).addTo(map)
})
```

The normal JSON response looks like this:

```js
{
  "ac": [{
    "alert": 0,
    "alt_baro": 31825,
    "alt_geom": 33700,
    "baro_rate": -1088,
    "dir": 251.6,
    "dst": 233.229,
    "flight": "ET617   ",
    "gs": 387.8,
    "hex": "040133",
    "lat": 9.549694,
    "lon": 43.403378,
    "messages": 7377556,
    "mlat": [],
    "nac_p": 8,
    "nac_v": 2,
    "nic": 0,
    "r": "ET-AUB",
    "rc": 0,
    "rssi": -18.1,
    "seen": 1,
    "seen_pos": 1804.391,
    "sil": 2,
    "sil_type": "unknown",
    "spi": 0,
    "t": "A359",
    "tisb": [],
    "track": 262,
    "type": "mode_s"
  },
  {
```

Comment: Eventhough I know what you mean stackoverflow is intended for more straight forward to the point questions instead of general advice. If you don't now how to do something that's okay, state clearly what you want to accomplish in a question form.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a GeoJSON feature you can create directly a Leaflet layer:

```
  var options = {
    radius: 8,
    fillColor: "#ff7800",
    color: "#000",
    weight: 1,
    opacity: 1,
    fillOpacity: 0.8
  };

  if(response.data.ac.length > 0) {
    var polyline = L.polyline([], options);
    response.data.ac.forEach((point) => {
      polyline.addLatLng([point.lat, point.lng]);
    });

    polyline.addTo(map);
  }
```